# parsing "The shop stocks everything from cigarettes to recycled loo paper."

Tags: parsing, appositives, supplementation

[thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/stock):
**(1)** *The shop stocks everything from cigarettes to recycled loo paper*.

Am I right that?:
The noun phrase "*everything from cigarettes to recycled loo paper*" is the direct object of "*stocks*".
The prepositional phrase "*from cigarettes to recycled loo paper*" is a supplement.
"*Everything*" is the anchor of this supplement.

If I'm not right, then:
Why not?
What does the prepositional phrase "*from cigarettes to recycled loo paper*" function as?

---

Am I right that?:
"*From cigarettes to recycled loo paper*" is not an appositive to "*everything*" because if we remove "*everything*":
**(2)** *The shop stocks from cigarettes to recycled loo paper*.
then (2) is ungrammatical since "*from cigarettes to recycled loo paper*" is a prepositional phrase and, therefore, can't be a direct object of the transitive verb "*stocks*".

If I'm not right, then:
Why not?

Comment: Yes: "everything [from cigarettes to recycled loo paper]" is an NP functioning as object of "stocks". I'd say that the bracketed PP is complement of "everything" since that is the head that licenses it.

Comment: @BillJ Does "_a grin from ear to ear_" have the same parse? I mean the PP “_from ear to ear_” is the complement of “_a grin_”. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

*Everything from A to Z* is a way of saying 'all kinds of things'. Usually A and Z are things at opposite ends of some kind of scale (large to small, elegant to utilitarian); I'm not sure what the criteria for mentioning cigarettes and toilet rolls are!